# type string is not assignable to type MenuItems[]

Tags: angular9

i am storing json data to session but while retrieving it shows below error

error : type string is not assignable to type MenuItems[]

this.datasource.data=sessionStorage.getItem('MenuData')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only store string in sessionStorage, by using JSON.stringfy() and while retrieving use JSON.parse() method